# Is the Martian madness event in terraria mobile?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have already been searching for around 5 weeks now and I have made a skybridge to both ends of the world and I was wondering if it was actually in mobile.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Terraria wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Martian_Madness), the Martian Madness event is currently desktop only, so it is not available on mobile devices or consoles.